# Generating a graph with multiple (sets of multiple sets of multiple) X-axis data sets

Tags: python, perl, matplotlib, graphing

I am looking for a way to generate a graph with multiple sets of data on the X-axis, each of which is divided into multiple sets of multiple sets.  I basically want to take [this graph](http://gdgraph.com/samples/sample1A.html) and place similar graphs side by side with it.  I am trying to graph the build a graph of the duration (Y-axis) of the same jobs (0-3) with different configurations (0-1) on multiple servers (each group with the same 8 jobs).  Hopefully the following diagram will illustrate what I am trying to accomplish (smaller groupings are separated by pipes, larger groupings by double pipes):

```
|| 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 || 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 || 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 | 0 1 ||
|| 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   || 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   || 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   ||
|| Server 1              || Server 2              || Server 3              ||
```

Is this possible with either the GD::Graph Perl module or the matplotlib Python module?  I can't find examples or documentation on this subject for either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some Python code that will produce what you're looking for.  (The example uses 3 configurations rather than 2 to make sure the code was fairly general.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

nconfigs, njobs, nservers = 3, 4, 4

width = .9/(nconfigs*njobs)  
job_colors = [(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (1,0,1)]

def dim(color, fraction=.5):
    return tuple([fraction*channel for channel in color])

plt.figure()
x = 0
for iserver in range(nservers):
    for ijob in range(njobs):
        for iconfig in range(nconfigs):
            color = dim(job_colors[ijob], (iconfig+2.)/(nconfigs+1))
            plt.bar(x, 1.+random.random(), width, color=color)
            x += width
    x += .1

plt.show()
```

This code is probably fairly transparent.  The odd term `(iconfig+2.)/(nconfigs+1)` is just to dim the colors for the different configurations, but keep them bright enough so the colors can be distinguished.

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Now, how do I generate _X groups of_ Y groups of bars?

Comment: I've edited my answer (both the code and words below it) to address the X groups of Y bars, or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "X groups of Y bars"?  The figure shows "5 groups of 7 bars", right?

Comment: You're right, perhaps I worded my problem incorrectly.  What I really am looking for is a way to make a graph of X groups of Y groups of Z groups of bars.  I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I think I got it now.  Just for the completeness of the answer, I modified my code and figure to match better what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I saw a graph that I think does what you want using
[protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/antibiotics-burtin.html)

I have no experience with the program, but the graph was enlightening and I think would give you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) can do it easily and it have Python interface too. See [this](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/1d_plots.html) for examples.